# How to handle .mbp files within android or windows?

Tags: android, windows, archive

i have a .mbp file generated by one of my android applications.

This is NOT a MobilePocketreader file. It is a Mediabase Package file.

Can some android library handle it (probably does), or can some windows app handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I understood how to solve this.

Its surprising that no one could answer this.

You can simply use the sqlite browser to browse through the entire table set and data.